# Spring MVC App index.jsp not showing in browser, HTTP 404 result

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, ant

I've been following a (slightly outdated) tutorial on creating a Spring MVC app here:

https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

I've created the build.xml, build.properties, and war/index.jsp files according to the tutorial. Also created a war/WEB-INF directory containing web.xml. I have seen that a common error is directory structure and I've checked to see sure mine is correct. Also made sure paths are correct.

My build file compiles, builds, and deploys correctly with Ant. I am not understanding why the the command "> ant list" results in a "stopped" status instead of "running", however. See execution below.

Is there something I am missing for the index.jsp resource to be found by my browser? I am not sure what else to do at this point.

Are there other good MVC tutorials with Spring? This seemed the most in-depth.

```
Tom:springapp tom$ ant 
Buildfile: /Users/tom/Projects/springapp/build.xml

usage:
     [echo] 
     [echo] springapp build file
     [echo] -----------------------------------
     [echo] 
     [echo] Available targets are:
     [echo] 
     [echo] build     --> Build the application
     [echo] deploy    --> Deploy application as directory
     [echo] deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file
     [echo] install   --> Install application in Tomcat
     [echo] reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat
     [echo] start     --> Start Tomcat application
     [echo] stop      --> Stop Tomcat application
     [echo] list      --> List Tomcat application
     [echo] 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Tom:springapp tom$ ant build
Buildfile: /Users/tom/Projects/springapp/build.xml

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Tom:springapp tom$ ant deploy
Buildfile: /Users/tom/Projects/springapp/build.xml

build:

deploy:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Tom:springapp tom$ ant list
Buildfile: /Users/tom/Projects/springapp/build.xml

list:
 [list] OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
 [list] /:running:0:ROOT
 [list] /examples:running:0:examples
 [list] /host-manager:running:0:host-manager
 [list] /springapp:stopped:0:springapp
 [list] /manager:running:0:manager
 [list] /docs:running:0:docs

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

If I try to reach my app through my browser:

http://localhost:8080 -> gets the Tomcat landing page

"___________________"/manager/html -> works OK w/login

"___________________"/springapp/index.jsp -> results in HTTP 404

Not sure what else to do. I've checked for typos in all files. Adjusted for newer versions of Tomcat and Java. Source files are below.

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="springapp" basedir="/Users/tom/Projects/springapp"    default="usage">
<property file="build.properties"/>

<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<property name="name" value="springapp"/>

<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="servlet-api.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="{$build.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="usage">
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="${name} build file"/>
    <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
    <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
    <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
    <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
    <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
    <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
    <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
    <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat application"/>
    <echo message=""/>
</target>

<target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="S{build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.8.0_60" target="1.8.0_60" debug="true"
        deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true" includeantruntime="true">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
</copy>
</target>

<target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
    <war destfile="${name}.war"
        webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xmL">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </war>
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}" presevelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.war"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<!-- Tomcat tasks -->

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
     <fileset dir="/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.3/libexec/lib">
       <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
       <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
       <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.3/libexec/bin">
        <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="start" description="Start application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="list" description="List application in Tomcat">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>

<!-- End Tomcat tasks -->
```

springapp/build.properties:

```
#Ant properties for building the springapp

appserver.home=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.3/libexec

appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

springapp/war/index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head><title>Example :: Spring Application</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example - Spring Application</h1>
        <p>This is my test.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

springapp/war/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="httpL//java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>
    index.jsp
  </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>"
```

Comment: *"Not sure what else to do."* You look at the Tomcat log files, to see what error prevented the webapp from starting.

Comment: Post your controller

Comment: @bmarkham - no controller specified by tutorial at this point

Comment: @Andreas - thanks for pointing me to logs.

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas mentioned to check logs.

There are several Tomcat log files, the one I found the most useful with and with most information was catalina.*date*.log. It showed stack traces and from there I was able to pinpoint a typo in my web.xml file at the very end.

After I addressed the typo, I was able to successfully access index.jsp.